# Begin programming for iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios

I have been coding in c#, a bit java and some web-programming with HTML and css. Now I want to begin programming for iPhone.

I have been reading some about the techniques and now I can´t decide if I shall learn JavaScript and go for HTML/CSS/JavaScript or learn Objective-c. What do you think are the smoothest way to learn iPhone programming? Any tips?

I just need some push in the beginning then it´s just training, training and more training.

I appreciate your time and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Stanford lectures are number one.
Here is the [link](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall).

Comment: Thanks, and he´s using Objective-c right?

Comment: Thanks for your answear I liked the lectures and will foloow them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make apps for iPhone and android in javascript using the [AppMobi platform](http://www.appmobi.com/) or int HTML/CSS with "Sencha Touch". If you want to go native, you'll have to start with learning objective-C. Once you're comfortable, the [apple developer](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) site is a good place. Or you can refer to [Stanford's lectures](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall)

Comment: Thanks for your answear I liked the lectures and the other linc were interesting to.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should brush up with [**objective c**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) concepts.
Once you have gone through it, you can start with [**apple's iphone library**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/).
After have an idea about basics, you can then start with [**basic iphone tutorials**](http://www.icodeblog.com/). I must suggest you [**Ray Wenderlich**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) awesome IPhone tutorials which I consider are the best.
Other than this, you can always Google around for other tutorials.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answear I´ll go with Objective-c and will read alot and follow many tutorials and hope I´ll learn some.